# Guide to install xampp with zope-plone on the same linux machine?

Tags: python, apache, xampp, plone, zope

Is there a good step by step online guide to install xampp (apache server,mysql server) together with zope-plone on the same linux machine and make it play nicely or do I have to go through their confusing documentations?
Or how can I install this configuration in the best way? I can install and use both seperately but in tandem is an issue for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for wrong site but I just figured out that it was not a problem at all. I installed XAMPP (a snap) and downloaded and ran the plone install script. Both sites XAMPP on port 80 and zope/plone on 8080 are working without problems. Just to let everyone know. I don't know why I got nervous about this :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://fedorasolved.org/server-solutions/installing-zope-plone-on-fedora)?

By the way, I think this question belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) (administrative questions), not stackoverflow.com (programming questions).

Comment: sorry for wrong site but I just figured out that it was not a problem at all. I installed XAMPP (a snap) and downloaded and ran the plone install script. Both sites XAMPP on port 80 and zope/plone on 8080 are working without problems. Just to let everyone know. I don't know why I got nervous about this :)